# This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'React Node', but multiple children were provided. when tried using typescript in return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

This is my code below
and the error description is as follows.
**(property) JSX.IntrinsicElements.div: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes, HTMLDivElement>**
Iam not able to use code in return statement as I wrote the map statement below I have got this error.

````
import '../styles/sidebar.css'

const sidebar:React.FC = () => {
  var a=[1,2,3]
  
  return (
    
    <div className="sidebar">
      {
        a.map((aa) => console.log(11))
      }
      <ul className="sdebar_lst">
        <li className="lsthead">Departments</li>
        <li id="it" className="list_elm1">IT</li>
        <li id="hr" className="list_elm1">Human Resources</li>
        <li id="md" className="list_elm1">MD</li>
        <li id="sales" className="list_elm1">Sales</li>
      </ul>
</div>```
````

Comment: Can you repor it here : https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-butterfly-efglrh?file=/src/App.tsx:158-551

Comment: Remove the `{ a.map((aa) => console.log(11)) }` from the JSX.

Comment: That I Know I want to know how can I use typescript in between react return statement